How do I force a Mako function to require named arguments?
With Python, you can require arguments to be named when a function is called, e.g.
def myfunc (a, b, *, c, d):
   print(f"arguments c and d must be named arguments")

myfunc(1,2,3,4)

>>> TypeError: myfunc() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

That same syntax doesn't seem to work for me when defining a Mako function:
from mako.template import Template
s = """\
<%def name="myfunc (a, b, *, c, d)">
I want to require that arguments c=${c} and d=${d} are named
</%def>
${myfunc(1,2,3,4)}
"""
print(Template(s).render())

>>> I want to require that arguments c=3 and d=4 are named

The * doesn't cause a syntax error, so it appears that Mako is just ignoring it. Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to accomplish the forcing of named arguments?

You usually do smth like this: def myfunc (a, b, c, d, *args):

I don't want to allow additional arguments beyond the four I specified, which is what I believe your example is doing. I just want to allow arguments a and b to be positional, while requiring arguments c and d to be named.

You cannot force named arguments right now.  It seems like a bug in the implementation.  Also it looks like positional only arguments probably wouldn't work but I think these were added much later.  I'm not sure if this was intended but this feature was added forever ago so now it would probably be hard to "fix".
For example this test will fail with the current implementation:
    def test_def_py3k_kwonly_as_pos(self):
        """ Test that using position arg for kwonly argument fails. """
        template = Template(
            """
        <%def name="kwonly(one, *, two)">
            look at all these args: ${one} ${two}"""
            """
        </%def>

        ${kwonly('one', 'two')}"""
        )
        assert_raises_message(TypeError, "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given", template.render)

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/mako/commit/836e5f97e84088cd3104cb3a30bf02e8a6c0a9a5

The link you provided added test case test_def_py3k_args, which shows that the implementation requires the * to prefix one of the arguments instead of being an argument on its own. So, defining my arguments as (a, *b, c, d) would force c and d to be named. Not exactly Python syntax, but I tried it and it works. I would also like to be able to force all arguments to be named. But with this syntax, the best I can do is (*a, b, c, d), which means a can still be positional. So I may have to create a dummy argument that I just check is always None unless you have another idea.

I updated my answer to be more explicit that it isn't currently possible.  You could do some work-around but seems like maybe it could be fixed.  Just not sure about backwards compatibility because people might have accidentally depended on it.

Thanks for the help. I was wrong about the "Not exactly Python syntax" comment above. The *b will collect all remaining positional arguments into a tuple, just like Python does. That means I do have a reasonable workaround, which I posted as a second answer.

I chose @Ian Wilson's response as the correct answer, but I wanted to post my workaround as well.
Because Mako supports the *arg syntax, you can create a dummy collector and then check that the dummy tuple is empty:
<%def name="myfunc (a, b, *dummy, c, d)">
<% assert dummy==(), "only two positional arguments allowed" %>
I want to require that arguments c=${c} and d=${d} are named
</%def>

This will return an error if more than two positional arguments are supplied, but c and d can still be given if they are named, e.g. ${myfunc(1,2,c=3,d=4)}
